# Validacion Windows desde Razor Page

Tags: visual-studio, mvc, razor, .net-6.0

Estoy actualizando una aplicacion que funciona en una intranet, de web forms (framework 4.8) a razor page (net 6).
Para obtener un usuario de windows usando web form, hacia lo siguiente :

```
Session("Usuario") = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Pero estoy viendo que en razor page no es tan sencillo; ya he puesto en true a windowsAuthentication y en false a anonymousAuthentication en el archivo launchSetting.json, y lo que me muestra es una pantalla (ver imagen) para que el usuario ingrese sus credenciales de autentificación, lo cual no es lo que requiero, ya que el usuario ya se valido previamente al dominio (al prender todas las mañanas su maquina en la empresa).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veo que con la siguiente instruccion se obtiene el usuario de red en Razor, y funciona, pero siempre y cuando me valide previamente en la pantalla de la imagen.

```
var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Tambien he probado adicionando lo siguiente en Program.cs, pero igual siempre mes muestra dicha pantalla.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Por favor si me pueden indicar como obtener el usuario de windows sin volver a registrarme, o en todo caso indicar si esta es la forma normal de trabajar en Razor Page.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías inyectar la interfaz IHttpContextAccessor

En Program.cs  colocar
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Luego su clase o controlador:

```
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UsuarioService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public string ObtenerUsuario()
    {
        var usuario = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) ? string.Empty : usuario;
    }
```